# How to halt the execution of a python script using a different python script?

Tags: python

I have a program that executes another program using os.system

I would like to have it also halt the execution of said program based on a counter.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by counter? Do you mean after certain amount of time?

Comment: I mean after a certain amount of iterations of the script that it calls.